# Webmail does not receive from outside my domain

Tags: godaddy, webmail, route53

I have my mail server hosted in Godaddy. My domain is also registered in godaddy but, I have third-party name servers which is Route53 from aws. I have my website there. Now, for the mail server i wanted to keep using godaddy hosting. So, I created these records in Route 53 hosted zone.

```
Type     Name               Value

A        mail.sheba.xyz     166.62.10.36

MX       mail.sheba.xyz     1 mail.sheba.xyz

TXT      mail.sheba.xyz     "v=spf1 a mx include:secureserver.net ~all"
```

Now, my mail is working fine except that no emails from outside my domain is not received. I can send to outside domains though. What could be the problem here? I followed this: [Why won't webmail receive emails from outside my domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63113/why-wont-webmail-receive-emails-from-outside-my-domain). But, does not seem to solve my issue. And it's almost five days, after I switched the name servers.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy uses email servers that are not hosted on the same server as your web hosting. This happens to be rather common for many shared hosting web companies. In order to use GoDaddy's email with your domain you need to point your domain records to the correct addresses. Pointing to your domain is not the correct procedure as you will need to point your records to their email server which is `secureserver.net`.

*Your MX DNS records should look something like this:*

> **SOURCE:** [**Using GoDaddy for Email**](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-can-I-point-my-e-mail-towards-GoDaddy)
>
> US MX Records
>
> ```
> Fully Qualified Host  Type    Priority    Value
> yourdomain.com    MX  10  mailstore1.secureserver.net
> yourdomain.com    MX  0   smtp.secureserver.net
> ```
>
> EU MX Records
>
> ```
> Fully Qualified Host  Type    Priority    Value
> yourdomain.com    MX  10  mailstore1.europe.secureserver.net
> yourdomain.com    MX  0   smtp.europe.secureserver.net
> ```
>
> AS MX Records
>
> ```
> Fully Qualified Host  Type    Priority    Value
> yourdomain.com    MX  10  mailstore1.asia.secureserver.net
> yourdomain.com    MX  0   smtp.asia.secureserver.net
> ```

Comment: Where should I put these? Route 53?

Comment: Whomever is managing your DNS... if Route 53, then yes.

Comment: Does not work yet.

Comment: now google says, Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain sheba.xyz by smtp.asia.secureserver.net. [182.50.144.66].

Comment: You can find out why it was rejected by looking at the email header response. To be honest you should speak to GoDaddy... that's what they are there for. The settings I provided is from there website, if you have an issue then you need to talk to them.

Comment: And they said, its not their issue. So, they wont do anything. And the header is quite long and all written in gibberish, i can't understand a thing. And everyone out there is telling that, my MX records are wrong, but I dont know what should be right. Meanwhile, business mails are lost, and they kept pressurizing me.

Comment: Ask GoDaddy for the correct MX settings. How are you trying to send and receive emails?...